# equality of circular shifts for binary numbers

Tags: shift

I'm looking for a way to do cicular right shift with circular left shift in binary numbers
for example
number 1011
left circular shift 0111
right circular shift 1101
but I don't know how to do this?

Comment: It would help if you tagged your question with the language you are using and provided more information such as the number of bits you care about.

Comment: Also, show what you've tried so far and what were the results.

Comment: You've tagged your question with "shift", which is for "Questions related to the usage of the right and/or left shift key on the keyboard."

Comment: I don't want to use any programming language  now ,just I'm looking fot it's algorithm in general

Comment: I am designing a basic cpu which should have only one instruction for circular shifting but so I have to omit one of the shift instructions but if the other shift can be done

Answer (score 0):

At a left shif you just take the most-left number and add it at the end:

1000110 becomes 0001101 becomes 0011010

With the right shift it's vice versa, you take the right most number at the beginning and at it add the beginning:

1000110 becomes 0100011 becomes 1010001

So if n would be the length of your number, if you right shift x times it would be equal to a left shift n - x times, because after n shifts right or left you are back at your inital number.

Comment: tnx but I know this way and I'm looking for a way which doesn't need any loop for doing repeated actions like left shifting for n-x times

Comment: you could calculate the position of every new character: it would be always  start (position + shifts) % length for a right shift and (position - shifts) % length, assuming you start counting the positions from left to right and start with 0. To start with 1 just add 1

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand what you mean by calculating position of each character and how it can shift the number

Comment: I want to know if circular left shift and circular right shift have any relationship like for example one of them will be calculate by adding a special number to another or complementing them or not

Comment: What i meant is that if you right shift one time
it equals a left shift n - 1 times , with n as the size of your number:

For example:
01011011 , -> n = 8, if you left shift once : 01011011 -> 10110110
if you left shift 8-1 = 7 times: 01011011 -> 10101101 -> 11010110 -> 01101011 -> 10110101 -> 11011010 -> 01101101 -> 10110110